# How to convert string to long long

Tags: c++, string, long-integer, substr

All the solution I found seem to use atoll but that takes char while I have a string. For example I read an input $100, put it into a string and check if the first char is $. Then I need to convert the substring to a long long type.

```
int main() {

    long long price;
    string priceStr;

    cin>>priceStr;
    if (priceStr[0] == '$') {
        price = convertToLongLong(priceStr.substr(1));//how?
    }else{
        cerr<<"error!";
    }

}
```

My input is : $100
Thanks!

EDIT: Maybe I'm not doing it in a proper way. My input stream is ID Name $price #quantity like below and I need all numbers to be long long and also check if $ and # sighs are at right place:

1 TV $1500 #50

2 LAPTOP $2000 #30

Comment: Whatever you do, **don't** use that. How will you know whether the number was 0 or it encountered an error? There are `stoll`, `strtoll`, string streams, `boost::lexical_cast`, and others that all provide error checking.

Comment: ...you don't need a `long long` to store 100.

Comment: long long is needed, I'm just using 100 as an example... @ValekHalfHeart

Comment: Hi @chris For example if I use strtoll which takes (const char* str, char** endptr, int base), but I only have a string, what should I do then? Thanks.

Comment: @Arch1tect, Documentation for `std::string` clearly lists `c_str()` and `data()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a couple of options, if the STL is your only option:

```
int main() {

    long long price;
    string priceStr;

    cin>>priceStr;
    if (priceStr[0] == '$') {
        std::istringstream is (priceStr.begin() + 1, priceStr.end());
        is >> price;
        if (!is)
            cerr << "fail!" << endl;
    }else{
        cerr<<"error!";
    }
}
```

If you can use Boost:

```
int main() {

    long long price;
    string priceStr;

    cin>>priceStr;
    if (priceStr[0] == '$') {
        price = boost::lexical_cast<long long>(&*priceStr.begin() + 1, priceStr.size() -1); // throws if it cannot convert.
    }else{
        cerr<<"error!";
    }
}
```

Note that there's no bounds checking in the second example, you'd surely want to implement that before doing what I've shown above. (i.e. check that priceStr.size() >= 2).

As others have suggested, you could use variants of `stoll`, but be aware these functions don't report errors well, if at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm using your first method now and changed priceStr.begin() + 1, priceStr.end() to priceStr.substr(1)

Comment: You should handle failure of the other `cin` streaming operation too ala `if (std::cin >> priceStr) ... else ...;`.  As is you may access `[0]` on an empty string - undefined behaviour - then possibly attempt to construct a string where the start iterator is already past the end.

Comment: Tony D, that's why I noted that there's no bounds checking.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

scanf("$%lld", &price);

**edit**

See above reference.  Quick and easy way to format input.

```
if(scanf("%lld %s $%lld #%lld",
  &id, name, &price, &quantity)!=4) fprintf(stderr, "error!");
```

Otherwise see other answers for more common/standard solutions.

Comment: Note 1. this is c-style, 2. this isn't type-safe, 3. all of the above.  but it's quick and dirty ;)

Answer (score 0):

read the docs for string http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

there's a very obvious way to get a char* from a std::string in there

Answer (score 0):

Try to use                 stoll

please refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoll/

I never tried this